# How to remove port forwarding rule on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, port-forwarding

A command line application set up a rule to forward local port 8080 traffic to a VM's port 80. Something went wrong and left this definition. How can I find and remove this port forwarding rule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Memory

If it only modify the in memory rules, the laziest way is to reboot. If you want to remove the rule(s) without reboot, do following (assuming the program did not modify rule file)

```
pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf
```

That will reset+reload the default system rules. Thus removing the port forwarding rule(s).

### File

If the program modified the rule files, check following

```
/etc/pf.conf
/etc/pf.anchors/*
File/Directory referred in /etc/pf.anchors/com.apple
```

After modifying, do following

1. Check pf.conf for error first

   pfctl -nf /etc/pf.conf
2. If no error, deploy new rules without reboot

   pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf

Comment: Reboot seemed to do the trick. =]

Comment: `pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf` didn't remove the in memory rules for me...

Comment: @Ryan This is indeed similar for me, I've found I need to explicitly specify the anchor if I want to flush the relevant rules. (with -a)